# How are the values for the `sex` feature in sklearn Diabetes dataset obtained?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-scaling

I'm just starting out with using `sklearn` for my own Machine Learning project and I'm using `sklearn`'s built-in ["Diabetes" dataset](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/toy_dataset.html#diabetes-dataset).

While performing data exploration on the features, I noticed something a bit confusing to me about the `sex` feature. Here's the hist plot:

[image]

Now there are 2 things I do understand here:

1. The binary histogram makes sense, there are in this dataset 2 distinct 'sexes' of male and female.
2. Them being numerical also makes sense, as it appears all features in this dataset have already been 'normalized'.

**What I don't understand is why the values are the way they are? (See below for what the values are)**

```py
>>> from sklearn import datasets
>>> diab_df = datasets.load_diabetes(as_frame=True)
>>> features = diab_df['data']
>>> features.sex.unique()

array([ 0.05068012, -0.04464164])
```

How are these numbers derived? At first, I thought it could be some sort of stratified sampling, where if the true population distribution is say, 53% male, 47% female, then I'd maybe expect to see the values in this hist to be -0.47 & 0.53 or something?

Comment: Have a look at the standardization procedure: *"Note: Each of these 10 feature variables have been mean centered and scaled by the standard deviation times n_samples (i.e. the sum of squares of each column totals 1)."* When you apply this to the [un-standardized dataset](https://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~boos/var.select/diabetes.tab.txt) you should get the standardized values as in given in the sklearn dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data description says:

> Note: Each of these 10 feature variables have been mean centered and
> scaled by the standard deviation times `n_samples` (i.e. the sum of
> squares of each column totals 1).
> [https://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~boos/var.select/diabetes.html](https://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/%7Eboos/var.select/diabetes.html)
>
> For more information see: Bradley Efron, Trevor Hastie, Iain Johnstone and Robert
> Tibshirani (2004) "Least Angle Regression," Annals of Statistics (with
> discussion), 407-499.
> [http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/LARS/LeastAngle_2002.pdf](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/Papers/LARS/LeastAngle_2002.pdf)

```
from sklearn import datasets
print(datasets.load_diabetes())
```